# Installing pythonnet with no internet access

Tags: python, pip, conda, python.net

I am trying to install pythonnet on a machine with no internet access. On a connected machine I downloaded pythonnet-master.zip from Github, and pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz from pypi.

When I try `pip install pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz`, I get the error `The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org.`

I then used `conda install nuget-3.2.0.10516-py34_0.tar.bz2` to take care of nuget. The installation was successful, but I still cannot install pythonnet.

My attempts using pythonnet-master.zip and `conda install` also failed. Any ideas would be helpful.

Here is the full error output:

```
(raman_env) C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\eric\software>pip install pythonnet-2
.4.0.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\administrator\desktop\eric\software\pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonnet
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import s
ys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8jks801m\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8jks801m\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize
, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'
"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C
:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-vi5w5zft' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8jks801m\
  Complete output (44 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8jks801m\setup.py",
 line 658, in <module>
      zip_safe=False,
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_
_init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\core.py", line 1
48, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 9
66, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 9
85, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8jks801m\setup.py",
 line 610, in run
      return bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.run(self)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_
wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 31
3, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 9
85, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\command\build.py
", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 31
3, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 9
85, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\command\build_ex
t.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\command\build_ex
t.py", line 449, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\distutils\command\build_ex
t.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8jks801m\setup.py",
 line 245, in build_extension
      self._install_packages()
    File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8jks801m\setup.py",
 line 424, in _install_packages
      subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=use_shell)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\lib\subprocess.py", line 347,
in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'tools\nuget\nuget.exe update -self' re
turned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
  Running setup.py clean for pythonnet
Failed to build pythonnet
Installing collected packages: pythonnet
  Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\raman_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import
 sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Loc
al\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8jks801m\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI
~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8jks801m\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokeni
ze, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\
n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --recor
d 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-31isrm6o\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8jks801m\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ra
man_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'
C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8jks801m\\setup.py'"'"'
; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8jks801
m\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__,
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rec
ord-31isrm6o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile C
heck the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Same error after installing "nuget"?

Comment: yes the same error

Comment: Could you post the full output of `pip install pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz`

Comment: @FlyingTeller I added the full output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setup.py` of `pythonnet` is trying to run `nugget.exe update --self` which fails in you system because of the missing internet connection. I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Instead of a source install, try to download the right `whl` file. On pypi, there are only ones for cp37 and below. If you are running pyhton 3.8, you can find the right wheel file [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonnet)
2. Extract the tar.gz archive and comment line 424: `subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=use_shell)`. Then run `python setup.py install`. This will prevent setup from trying to update nugget during the installation process

Comment: Installing from wheel worked. Thank you for your help.