# When a new version 3.X of Python is released, does it always require the Python.Net development team to release a new version of Python.Net?

Tags: python.net

I have a project that uses Python.Net for which I specify to customers that they need 'Python 3.6 or later'. However, when for example, Python 3.10 becomes the current default download from Python.org, does this mean that there will be a period of time where my applicaion won't work because Python.Net hasn't been updated to work with Python 3.10?

Or do I have to tell customers an upper bound value for the required Python verion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That strongly depends on how are you distributing Python.NET.

If you are shipping Python.NET before 3.0 (3.0 has not been released yet) with your .NET app, it can only work with the specific python version it has been built for.

If you are asking users to install Python.NET using `pip`, I think it is possible to [do it from source](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation#github-installation-from-master-branch), in which case it should work with any Python 3.6+. You can check that by installing Python 3.10 preview and trying from there. Wheels of course are only built for existing python versions.

Python.NET 3.0 should be able to support future Python 3.x versions once released. But right now it is in flux, and the next release might take 6-12 months: many features are still being developed and/or reworked.

Comment: Thanks @Lost,

I need to use official Python.Net releases so it looks like my only option until Python.NET 3.0 is:
1) I bundle the 8 Python.Net wheel files for Python 3.6 to Python 3.9 (win32 and amd64 versions) from https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/#files
2) My installer checks the current Python version and calls 'pip install' with the matching wheel file.
3) My user documentation specifies 'Python 3.6 to 3.9'
4) When a new version of Python.Net is released that supports Python 3.10 I make a new release of my application that includes the new wheel files.

Do you agree?

Comment: Re: "I think it is possible to do it from source". How can I do this with version 2.5.2? I tried 'pip download pythonnet' which gets pythonnet-2.5.2.tar.gz and pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl, but pip install C:\pythonnet_download\pythonnet-2.5.2.tar.gz gives an error. See details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116746/installing-pythonnet-with-no-internet-access
I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @Vince , the error you mentioned is due to installer trying to access the Internet. Is working offline your requirement?

Comment: Yes, I'd like an offline installer.